error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.`
In a Jenkins workflow, I have a Powershell step calling a docker login:
echo "$Env:DOCKER_PASSWORD" | docker login --username "$Env:DOCKER_USERNAME" --password-stdin jedox.azurecr.io

Before that step, I bind the credentials to the variables DOCKER_USERNAME and DOCKER_PASSWORD:

But when the workflow is running on a Windows machine, I get the error message
 Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.`

Any idea how to solve this problem?
